# How to remove/edit element in XML file using Python

Tags: python, xml

I have below XML file:

```
<annotation>
    <folder>JPEGImages</folder>
    <filename>01FQ0YY92XRX5MDWGYC2RJ1CP4.jpeg</filename>
    <path>D:\aVisionData\PVL Pilot Project\test\Annotation\JPEGImages\01FQ0YY92XRX5MDWGYC2RJ1CP4.jpeg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>601</width>
        <height>844</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>smallObject</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>329</xmin>
            <ymin>199</ymin>
            <xmax>376</xmax>
            <ymax>242</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

I want to remove `<path>` and also want to edit `<source> </source>` so it looks like below

```
<annotation>
    <folder>JPEGImages</folder>
    <filename>01FQ0YY92XRX5MDWGYC2RJ1CP4.jpeg</filename>
    <source>
        <database>objects</database>
        <annotation>custom</annotation>
        <image>custom</image>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>601</width>
        <height>844</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>smallObject</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>329</xmin>
            <ymin>199</ymin>
            <xmax>376</xmax>
            <ymax>242</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

To remove the `<path>`, I used below code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Et

file_path = os.path.join(inputAnnotationPath, annotation)
tr = Et.parse(file_path)
for element in tr.iter():
    for subElement in element:
        print(subElement)
        if subElement.tag == "path":
            se = subElement.get("path")
            element.remove(subElement)
tr.write(sys.stdout)
```

It runs fine but not able to remove `path`. What changes I should do to remove the `path` and modify `source`.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938924/parsing-utf-8-unicode-strings-with-lxml-html).

Comment: It seems like a good job for XSLT which can be run from Python as well.

Comment: I concur with @MartinHonnen

Comment: I've run your code against the sample input XML and I can see that `path` is removed. I also see that `source` is unmodified, but there's no logic/code for that, so I'm not surprised. I'm running 3.8.9.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple if you can use lxml:

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
tr = etree.parse(file_path, parser=parser)

#select both <path> and <source> for removal
targets = [tr.xpath('//path')[0], tr.xpath('//source')[0]]

#select the destination for the new <source> element
destination = tr.xpath('//filename')[0]

#recreate <source>
new_source = """
     <source>
        <database>objects</database>
        <annotation>custom</annotation>
        <image>custom</image>
    </source>"""

#remove what needs to be removed
for target in targets:
    target.getparent().remove(target)

#insert the new <source> element
destination.addnext(etree.fromstring(new_source))

#save to file
with open("output.xml", "wb") as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(tr))
```

Comment: Where is `tr` declared? Looks like it should be the result of `etree.parse()`. And, nothing was said about `filename`.

Comment: @ZachYoung Oops! Good catch - fixed.